# pandas: no apparent way to set a column to the output of an apply function in python 3.8

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
def apply_inplace(df: DataFrame, columns: Union[str, List[str]], func: Callable):
    df.loc[:, columns] = df[columns].apply(func)  # why is this missing from pandas?
```

This is the function I have written.  This is compliant with any and all potential numpy arrays that I can think of.

It is compliant with the error message that the syntactically equivalent, but apparently functionally inequivalent example below spawns:

```
df[columns] = df[columns].apply(func)
```

I.E. this one, which clogs Google and Github issue arteries throughout the python development community:

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:494: SettingWithCopyWarning:
>
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
>
> self.obj[item] = s

ONLY ONE PROBLEM: COMPLYING WITH THIS RECOMMENDATION PRODUCES THE EXACT SAME ERROR.

I am confused because Pandas is an *`O(n*m)` data structure, but we have an O(n) micro-optimization here presenting the user with an **UNAVOIDABLE** O(n) **interpreted-code-implemented** implicit copy optimization artifact that there exists no use case for which an asymptotic run-time complexity speed up is gained in an `O(n*m)`* data setting.

How on earth does one avoid this extraordinarily incompetent warning?

Other than, say, forming a new dataframe and compelling a deep copy -- lazy or otherwise -- of the entire `O(n*m)` dataset **just to bypass an `O(n)` micro-opt.**

---

What I have tried that does not work:

```
def apply_inplace(df: DataFrame, columns: Union[str, List[str]], func: Callable):
    df[columns] = numpy.asarray(df[columns].apply(func).values)

def apply_inplace(df: DataFrame, columns: Union[str, List[str]], func: Callable):
    df[columns] = deepcopy(numpy.asarray(df[columns].apply(func).values))

def apply_inplace(df: DataFrame, columns: Union[str, List[str]], func: Callable):
    df.loc[:,columns] = deepcopy(asarray(df[columns].apply(func).values))
```

---

What I have tried that *does* work, on a repeat basis.  Note: I have to explicitly force a deep `O(n*m)` copy:

```
def apply(df: DataFrame, columns: Union[str, List[str]], func: Callable, axis: int = 0) -> DataFrame:
    df2 = deepcopy(df)

    vfunc = np.vectorize(func) # at some point, this "became" necessary.
    df2[columns] = df[columns].apply(vfunc,axis)
    return df2
```

Alternatively, I could write about 10-30 lines of code where I carefully reconstruct data-frames and concatenate them together exactly the way they were.  Not a desirable solution.

Comment: Does the `df` you pass to your function come from some other operation that modifies the DataFrame? That is do you ever do something like `df = df[some_boolean_mask]` or `df = df.drop_duplicates()` before you pass it to `apply_inplace`?

Comment: @ALollz yes, occasionally.